# Kubernetes dashboard showing Unauthorized

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, kubeadm

I configured kubernetes cluster with one master and 4 worker nodes using KUBEADM tool IN LOCAL. All nodes are running fine. deployed an app and able access that app from browser. I have tried many ways to create a dashboard using kubectl but i am failed.

**TRY1:** tried directly with the below command:

```
$ sudo kubectl proxy --address="172.20.22.101" -p 8001
```

tried to access the dashboard using the url http://172.20.22.101:8001/api/v1, but it is saying unauthorized.

**TRY2:** created dashboard-admin.yaml file with the below content:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
   name: kubernetes-dashboard
   labels:
     k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   kind: ClusterRole
   name: cluster-admin
subjects:
-  kind: ServiceAccount
   name: kubernetes-dashboard
   namespace: kube-system
```

And run the below command:

```
$ kubectl create -f dashboard-admin.yaml
```

It's shown me: `clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created.`

Running the below command:

```
$ sudo kubectl proxy --address="172.20.22.101" -p 443
```

its running fine. I am accessing the http://172.20.22.101:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ URL from browser. it's showing same unauthorized error.

Comment: I am following the steps to install dashboard in this : https://www.assistanz.com/steps-to-install-kubernetes-dashboard/. When i try to access the site using the url: http://172.20.22.101:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/. it's showing connection refused. I observed the output in the nohup.out, it's showing the below error:I1203 12:28:05.880828   15591 log.go:172] http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused

Answer (score 2):

run kubectl proxy command  with **--accept-hosts** option

```
 kubectl proxy --address="172.20.22.101" -p 8001  --accept-hosts="^*$"
```

and it will work fine.

**Note: this is not recommended for production grade kubernetes clusters, since you're accessing the dashboard through plain http.**

More secure alternative is to run access the dashboard through ssh tunnel like this.

in one terminal run:

```
kubectl proxy
```

in another terminal run a ssh tunnel to localhost:8001 (the default kubernetes dashboard port)

```
ssh -NT -l SSH_USER -p SSH_PORT K8S_CONTROLLER_IP_ADDR -L 8001:localhost:8001
```

Comment: I've edited my answer, you've to allow traffic to reach the kubernetes dashboard from specific sources using --accept-hosts  option

Comment: i have executed kubectl proxy and done ssh from other terminal. when i do ssh. It's showing nothing.

Comment: I am executed  kubectl proxy --address="172.20.22.101" -p 8001  --accept-hosts="^*$". And trying to access the URL: http://172.20.22.101:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/ . it's showing a json response not the dashboard. Could you please tell me the url to get the dashboard

Comment: In case of ssh tunnel, the command will hold the tunnel open, and will output nothing, to access the dashboard use this url:

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/


and in case of using --accept-hosts options, you can use this url to access the dashboard:

http://172.20.22.101:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Comment: {
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"http:kubernetes-dashboard:\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}

Comment: kubernetes-dashboard service  running on 443 port.              
NAMESPACE     NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
default       kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          3d2h
default       wms1                   NodePort    10.101.136.116   <none>        8000:32261/TCP   4m31s
kube-system   kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP    3d2h
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.100.217.222   <none>        443/TCP          3m3

Comment: Check this issue:

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2406

it seems that describe the same issue you've, and it recommends reading
[Installation and Access Control guides on wiki pages](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Installation)

Comment: I am following the steps to install dashboard in this : assistanz.com/steps-to-install-kubernetes-dashboard. When i try to access the site using the url: 172.20.22.101:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/…. it's showing connection refused. I observed the output in the nohup.out, it's showing the below error:I1203 12:28:05.880828 15591 log.go:172] http: proxy error: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused –