# Access Kubernetes Dashboard on EC2 Remotely

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, remote-access, dashboard

I setup a K8s cluster in EC2 and launched kubernetes dashboard by following these links:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard
- https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control

Here are commands I ran:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'
```

As I setup a few IPs into security group for the EC2 instances, I assume only those IPs can access the dashboard, so no worry about the security here.

When I try to access the dashboard using:

```
http://<My_IP>:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

[image: error-msg]

Now what's the easiest way to access the dashboard?

I noticed there are several related questions, but seems no one really answer it.

Thanks a lot.

P.S. Just noticed some errors in Dashboard log. Something wrong with dashboard running?

[image: Dashboard Log Error]

Comment: Noticed some error from dashboard logs:

Comment: check this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53521962/kubernetes-dashboard-showing-unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

You can use service with `type:`[Loadbalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) and use `loadBalancerSourceRanges:` to limits access to your dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the ClusterRoleBinding for serviceaccount kubernetes-dashboard.? If not, apply the below yaml file changes, so that the serviceaccount will get cluster-admin roles to access all kubernetes resources.

```
   apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
   kind: ClusterRoleBinding
   metadata:
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
      labels:
           k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
   roleRef:
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      kind: ClusterRole
      name: cluster-admin
   subjects:
   -  kind: ServiceAccount
      name: kubernetes-dashboard
      namespace: kube-system
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what ServiceAccount or User you are using to connect to the kube-apiserver. If you want to have access without look for details of policy, literally give access to everything, your RBAC file can look similar to this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: my-cluster-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: <your-user-from-your-~/.kube/config>
```

Than pass a command:

```
kubectl apply -f <filename>
```

Second approach:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding my-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=<your-user-from-your-~/.kube/config>
```

You can also use a Group or ServiceAccount in User field. Look for official documentation about RBAC Authorization [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

Also what I found is great [tutorial](https://unofficialism.info/posts/accessing-rbac-enabled-kubernetes-dashboard/) if you wanna take it step by step.